# Is $A^tA$ Zariski dense in symmetric matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, bilinear-form

Let $k$ be a field with char$(k)\neq 2$, and $n$ be a positive integrer. Denote $\operatorname{M}_n(k)$ to be all $n\times n$ matrices over $k$.

Define $\mathcal{A}=\{A^tA\ |\ A\in\operatorname{M}_n(k)\}$, and $\mathcal{S}=\{A\in\operatorname{M}_n(k)|\ A^t=A\ \text{i.e. } A\text{ is a symmetric matrix.}\}$.

**Question1**: When does $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{S}$? (For example, when $n=1$, we know that $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{S}$ iff $k$ has no extension of degree 2.)

**Question2**: Is $\mathcal{A}$ Zariski dense in $\mathcal{S}$? If not in general, when it is dense? (For example, when $n=1$, we know that $\mathcal{A}$ in dense in $\mathcal{S}$ iff $|k|=\infty$)

**Question3**: Question 2, for $k=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I think $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{S}$ also when $n=1$ and $k$ is any perfect field of characteristic two (so in particular for all finite fields of characteristic two). This is probably very much a fringe case for you, but it does underline the need for a minor refinement to your statement in Q1. Such fields do have extensions of degree two.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks so much for pointing out that! You are right. I carelessly ignore the char=$2$ case. Persenally, char=2 is not the interesting case for me.

Comment: Understood. Characteristic two is rather pathological when working with bilinear/quadratic forms :-)